# where can i see the definition for function pthread_mutex_lock on ubuntu

Tags: c, pthreads, manpage, function-definition

The pthread library has a function `pthread_mutex_lock` which is used for locking purposes. I tried doing `man pthread_mutex_lock` but it didn't show any results. Is it stored somewhere on Linux or do I have to google it?

Comment: You need to install the manuals. Cf. [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/197369/1144515)

Comment: Thanlks That works